# In Jmeter, I have to divide number of thread into the multiple http requests in different percentage but have to keep sequence remain same

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, stress-testing

I am doing load testing on an ecommerce website by jmeter, where I have to divide number of thread into the multiple http requests in different percentage but have to keep sequence remain same as arranged in tree

Example:

```
Thread(1000)
    ++Login(20%)
    ++autoLogin(40.60%)
    ++addToCart(30.40%)
    ++Logout(9%)
```

To achieve percentage distribution, I have used Throughput Controller but execution sequence gets changed, causing failure of the whole test plan. Please suggest any other way to achieve.

Comment: Does your distribution have to be that precise, i.e. does it really matter that it's 40.6%, and not, around 40%? Also is Login and autoLogin alternatives, or do they need to run sequentially?

Comment: You can use weighted switch controller to achieve this. Here is the documentation of the plugin
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WeightedSwitchController/

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options to configure weighted load and highlight options provided by JMeter.

1. Different [***Thread Groups***](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) having different number of threads
2. [***Throughput Controller***](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
3. [***Switch Controller***](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) or [***Weighted Switch Controller***](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WeightedSwitchController/) plugins.

Here I will quote only the introduction of these three techniques, for complete detail please go through the Blazemeter blog on [***Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability***](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability). You could try to follow any one of the procedures stated in that blog.

- **Using Different Thread Groups with a Different Number of Threads:**

> Probably the easiest way to implement a distributed scenario when N%
>   of users execute task A, M% of users do task B, etc. is setting up
>   different test groups with the relevant percentage of virtual users
>   configured. For example, given the aforementioned scenario with
>   40%-30%-20%-10% distribution, we’ll need 4 Thread Groups having 40,
>   30, 20 and 10 threads correspondingly. You can divide or multiply
>   these numbers by any reasonable factor as per your load test plan; you
>   just have to make sure that the factor is the same.

- **Using Throughput Controller with Different Execution Percentages:**

> Throughput Controller is a slightly misleading name as it does not
>   control throughput (Constant Throughput Timer does - though to be fair
>   “Constant Throughput Timer” does not necessarily need to be “constant”
>   either, but that’s out of scope for this article). Instead of managing
>   throughput, the controller defines how often its child elements are
>   executed.

- **Using Switch Controller: Random Weighted Values:**

> Another option to determining the defined samplers' execution
>   percentage rate is using Switch Controller. Switch Controller provides
>   the option to run one of its subordinate samplers based on the “Switch
>   Value” which could be:
>
> - An integer - the child element which is index based on the Switch Value will be executed. The numbering is zero-based. If there is no
>     match or the Switch Value is blank/unset - the first child element
>     will be executed.
> - A string - the child element whose name equals the Switch Value string will be executed.

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks for information, comments on procedures 1. I can't use multiple threads because i want only one time i will have to change thread count only on one thread. 2. ThroughtPut controller.. i have tried but when i put each http request into the individual throughput controller..it calculates the defined percentage and execute respective http request first and execution sequence doesn't meet. 3. swich controller...controls which http request have to execute as defined....Still i have to meet sequecne with percentage distribution because each request is inter-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to make sure when using Throughput Controller that there are all childs.

So:

```
Thread(1000)
    ++Throughput Controller(20%)
    ++Login
        ++Throughput Controller(40.60%)
        ++autoLogin
        ++Throughput Controller(30.40%)
            ++addToCart
            ++Throughput Controller(9%)
            ++Logout
```