# JMeter: How to assign weights/frequencies/smapleRates to ThreadGroups/"TestSets" dynamically from CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I would like to create a JMeter test setup with important sampling and test variation parameters entirely controlled by csv-Files (i.e. not modifying the JMX-File). It should be run with maven.
Ideas is as follows:
sources.csv contains

```
sampleRate;file
40;samplesForController1.csv
30;samplesForController2.csv
5;samplesForController3.csv
...
```

SampleRate should determine, how often a certain number of tests (defined by parameters in the respective file) should be executed (relative to others).
How could this be achieved? Im asking for the first step here (make sure the files/testSamples are sampled/executed given the indicated sampleRate) as I think I can solve the second part (dealing with parameters in samplesForController1.csv etc.) by myself.

P.S.
I'm struggling with the options presented here: [In Jmeter, I have to divide number of thread into the multiple http requests in different percentage but have to keep sequence remain same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430526/in-jmeter-i-have-to-divide-number-of-thread-into-the-multiple-http-requests-in) since

1. afaics, thread groups cannot be created on-the-fly/dynamically/progammatically
2. apparently, Throughput Controller needs to know its child element(s probablities) upfront (i.e. not created dynamically), otherweise, sampling is very odd (I could not get it working maintaining the desired sampleRate)
3. I did not try to integrate jmeter-plugins in the maven build thus far as my impression is, the available plugins/controllers also needs to know their child element upfront

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is possible to create thread groups programmatically, check out:

   - [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
   - [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/) example project
   - [jmeter-java-dsl](https://github.com/abstracta/jmeter-java-dsl) project
2. You can use [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) and use a function like [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to generate the child element index, example implementation can be found in [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article
3. It's not a problem to use JMeter Plugins with Maven, see [Adding jar's to the /lib/ext directory](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath#adding-jars-to-the-libext-directory) documentation section for example setup

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers:
1. I wasn't aware that defining tests programmatically and via DSL is possible at all - very interesting - and this should have been my path to go in the first place...
2. I finally ended up with a much simpler approach: Use a Random Order Controller and determine the freq. of calling a specific sampleFile by its number of (repetitive appearances) in sources.csv. The freq. is a bit harder to see and control but it is very robust (compared to the other approaches I have tried)